# Has this crib been recalled? Should I not sell it?

Tags: safety, crib

We have a hand-me-down crib that has a drop side and I'd like to sell it but I'm wary of re-distributing a recalled crib. FWIW, We never used it because our first foster placement was much older than crib age and we're doing some purging as we get ready to move. I'm not prepared to move furniture for theoretical future children.

It definitely has drop sides. I'm guessing it is five or six years old. It's last tenant is four now, and I know it was given to her parents by another family. So it predates the drop-side ban.  But I put my whole weight on the drop side and it didn't budge. So it seems sturdy to me. And the [CPSC's poster](http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Safety-Education/Neighborhood-Safety-Network/Posters/Crib-Rules/) about crib safety says "Prohibit traditional drop sides" but actually shows the exact mechanism that this crib uses:

[image: Crib Safety]

Are there some drop-side cribs that are safe? Or should I be throwing this out/selling it only as a toddler bed?

PS. I did read [What should I look for in a crib?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-crib/13926#13926)

Comment: Without the make & model number, it's very hard to determine this. I don't think anyone can say for sure.

Comment: I'd take the drop side off and sell it as a toddler bed. We've used our ex-crib that way successfully for years :)

Answer (score 6):

According to the [CPSC](http://www.cpsc.gov/onsafety/2011/06/the-new-crib-standard-questions-and-answers/), you should not resell it and should disassemble it prior to discarding it.

> Is it okay for me as a consumer to resell, donate or give away a crib
>   that does not meet the new crib standards?
>
> > A consumer should not
> >     resell, donate or give away a crib that does not meet the new crib
> >     standards, such as trying to resell the product through an online
> >     auction site or donating to a local thrift store. CPSC recommends
> >     disassembling the crib before discarding it.
>
> Is the answer different if a piece (“immobilizer”) has been added to
>   my drop-side crib to prevent the side from moving up and
>   down?
>
> > Consumers should not sell or give away a drop-side crib that has
> >     an added immobilizer because it still will not meet the new crib
> >     standards.

Although your crib may appear similar to the crib in the poster, if it is more than four years old (manufactured before 2010) it is unlikely it meets the standard:

> How do I know whether the specific crib that I
>   own/use in my child care facility meets the new standards?
>
> > You cannot
> >     tell from looking at a crib whether it meets the new standards. It is
> >     not likely that cribs in use before the Commission issued its crib
> >     rule in December 2010 will comply with the new standards.

If you still know the model number and manufacturer, you can check with them, both about whether it is recalled, and whether it is safe:

> If you are considering purchasing new cribs that meet the standards, you may want
>   to ask the manufacturer or retailer whether the crib complies with 16
>   CFR 1219 (the new standard for full-size cribs) or 16 CFR 1220 (the
>   new standard for non-full-size cribs).